# How to create array and loop through in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Can someone please explain me how I can implement following to create array of events in my code?

I want to create something like following line in my code:

```
var array = calendar.fullCalendar('calendar');
    for(i in array){
    ......
    }
```

My code is here: [jsfiddle.net/jimil/8hqe3wxd/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/jimil/8hqe3wxd/3/)

So this line is not giving me array of all my events if I try like this:
calendar.fullCalendar('calendar');

Thank you & please let me know guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to get array of your events.

```
var array = calendar.fullCalendar("clientEvents");
// can loop array here.
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi it's not working as I received following error: Uncaught TypeError: calendar.fullcalendar is not a function. So if you can please let me know how I can resolve this error as your solution I already implemented earlier but gives me error. Secondly you can use jsfiddle link and send me fiddle link would be great help. Thanks

Comment: Sorry my mistake. C must be capital fullcalendar. I will edit my post.

Comment: Hi Bro its working thank you so much sorry for late reply as it was dinner time haha:) have a lovely day ahead.